# maven assembly plugin with preserved last modified timestamp

Tags: maven, timestamp, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm able to create a zip file using maven-assembly-plugin in my pom, but what I need to do is to make this zip has "lastmodified" timestamp of a directory that was zipped. Is it possible to achieve? 
I know I can use for example  maven-antrun-plugin and property preservelastmodified="true" when copying resources. Is there anything similar for creating archive of a file?

Comment: I would also like to know